# App is Crashing on iPod Touch First and Second Generation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipod-touch

My released app (Hidden London - Free App) has been reported as crashing on iPod touch 2nd and 3rd Generation. It works without issue on iPhone and iPad.

The crash log is as follows:

```
Wed Apr 13 09:03:40 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[908] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)

Wed Apr 13 09:03:40 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[908] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/E509FC07-A742-4483-95B1-7393B3F129B9 [69] (sandbox)

Wed Apr 13 09:03:40 unknown sandboxd[911] <Notice>: HiddenLondon(908) deny file-write-data /private/var/mobile/Applications/E509FC07-A742-4483-95B1-7393B3F129B9/HiddenLondon.app/HiddenLondon.sqlite

Wed Apr 13 09:03:40 unknown HiddenLondon[908] <Warning>: Not purchased: com.Beutelkind.HiddenLondon.ExtraPlaces

Wed Apr 13 09:03:40 unknown HiddenLondon[908] <Warning>: Not purchased: com.Beutelkind.HiddenLondon.RemoveAds

Wed Apr 13 09:03:42 unknown securityd[910] <Error>: OCSPResponse: now + maxAge > latestNextUpdate, using latestNextUpdate

Wed Apr 13 09:03:42 unknown com.apple.SpringBoard[24] <Notice>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence 500

Wed Apr 13 09:04:00 unknown HiddenLondon[908] <Warning>: ADBannerView: WARNING A banner view (0x159470) has an ad but may be obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view.

Wed Apr 13 09:04:31 unknown configd[22] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel memory event (90), free: 323, active: 1250, inactive: 1494, purgeable: 0, wired: 7841

Wed Apr 13 09:04:31 unknown configd[22] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created

Wed Apr 13 09:04:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.AdSheetPhone[0xabc0]) Exited: Killed

Wed Apr 13 09:04:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.Beutelkind.HiddenLondon[0x2fef]) Exited: Killed

Wed Apr 13 09:04:31 unknown SpringBoard[24] <Warning>: Received memory warning. Level=1

Wed Apr 13 09:04:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x736e]) Exited: Killed

Wed Apr 13 09:04:31 unknown SpringBoard[24] <Warning>: Received memory warning. Level=1

Wed Apr 13 09:04:32 unknown SpringBoard[24] <Warning>: Application 'AdSheet' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed

Wed Apr 13 09:04:32 unknown SpringBoard[24] <Warning>: Application 'HiddenLondon' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed

Wed Apr 13 09:04:32 unknown SpringBoard[24] <Warning>: Application 'Mail' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed

Wed Apr 13 09:04:32 unknown SpringBoard[24] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal (56%). Delaying auto-relaunch of 'Mail' for 30 seconds.

Wed Apr 13 09:04:32 unknown SpringBoard[24] <Warning>: Received memory warning. Level=1

Wed Apr 13 09:04:33 unknown ReportCrash[917] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2011-04-13-090433.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
```

Could anyone help me start to troubleshoot why this might be happening on the iPod Touch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hint to why your app is crashing is `Received memory warning. Level=1`. You're out of memory. This could be the amount of RAM your app is using for data structures, but I've more typically seen this type of error when you run out of graphics memory - i.e. the memory used to composite views, cache images, etc. The total amount of RAM on gen 1 and 2 iPod touches is only 128MB. Gen 3 and 4 bumped that to 256MB.

The memory related info in your log starts with `jetsam: kernel memory event (90), free: 323, active: 1250, inactive: 1494, purgeable: 0, wired: 7841`, which is a "low memory" warning message. You then see a whole bunch of apps being terminated by the OS (`Exited: Killed` and `exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed`). This is the documented behaviour of iOS in low memory conditions - it kills apps until it has enough free memory.

Comment: Odrm - thank you for your helpful answer. How can I further troubleshoot this with what I have - an iPhone 4, iPad and the SDK Simulators ?

Comment: I don't believe there's an alternative to on-device testing (see [setting memory in iPhone Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545847)). But you could track down memory usage with `Instruments` as a starter...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your application is using a lot of memory, and as a result it gets killed by the operating system.