# Is there any way to set simulator to work on limited memory?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode5

As we all know that simulator has more memory than devices. Generally for `unit testing` every developer use simulator before test project on device but sometimes in the case of unavailability of device, Is this possible to set simulator work on the limited memory?

For example is there any option in tool bar to set simulator's memory on 16GB/ 32GB memory so that it will work in the same way an iPad having 16Gb memory works if we set memory limitation to 16GB.

Comment: Please check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545847/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-amount-of-memory-available-in-the-iphone-simulator

Comment: A emulator duplicates a computer. A simulator imitates a computer. Because a simulator is radically different underneath, it would be very difficult to calculate the memory use. Thus, this feature is not and won't ever be implemented. You have to use the Allocation instrument and eyeball memory usage.

Comment: Well, Thanks guys.. really helpful information...!!!!

Comment: Do note that there's an option in the simulator to simulate a memory warning.  This can be useful for testing code that responds to memory warnings.

Comment: Note that 16/32GB is the _flash storage_ that is available to these devices, not the memory. When talking about memory, memory warnings and so forth, we are referring to the RAM. Each generation of phone has the same amount of RAM (usually more than the one before, but not always), regardless of the flash storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will solve your question :- 
 [Is there a way to set the amount of memory available in the iPhone Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545847/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-amount-of-memory-available-in-the-iphone-simulator)
**Update(Copying the content of below link):-**
 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3870841?tstart=0

*Not possible.   The simulator is an OS X application and thus you have no control over memory allocation. For details, read the part about OS X memory management here:* 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/ManagingMemory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000160i.

**Update 2:-**
`Even though iOS Simulator is a useful tool, never make it the only way you test an app. Because iOS Simulator is an app running on a Mac, it has access to the computer’s memory, which is much greater than the memory found on a device. As a result of the increased memory, iOS Simulator is not an accurate test of an app’s memory usage. For this same reason, you should always test the performance of your app’s user interface (UI) on a device. In iOS Simulator, your app’s UI may appear to run both faster and smoother than on a device.`

Reference link:- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html

Comment: You should copy the contents of those links here in case the links go broken. Otherwise you risk your answer being marked as “not an answer” and removed.

Comment: Yes, I should, but above links are working. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @PiyushDubey: The links are working _now_, but they might stop working in the future. That's why it's considered best practice to quote the most important/relevant parts of a linked article: your answer would become useless to a future visitor if the linked stopped working. (Exception are links to StackOverflow questions/answers; you don't need to quote those)