# Can we customize the RAM size in the xcode simulator somehow

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, applescript, appium-ios

I want to test my project mobile app installation in a very low memory device. Lets say in around 1 GB. The `xcode` comes with the defined RAM sizes.

Is there any way I can customize the RAM size in `xcode` like I can do in Android studio.

If yes, how?

If not, is there any other alternative or simulator type which I can use for this testing?

Comment: please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545847/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-amount-of-memory-available-in-the-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using a specific device in your simulator - iPhone 5 and 5S have 1 GB of RAM.

There's no point in specifying different amount of RAM than that of an actual device - since iOS is a closed ecosystem, you will never run your app on a device with, for example, 1.5 GB of RAM, because such device doesn't exist.

So, to test your app for devices with different amount of ram, use appropriate simulator:
1 GB - iPhone 5, 5S
2 GB - 6, 6 Plus, 6S, 6S Plus, SE, 7, 8
3 GB - 7 Plus, 8 Plus, X

If you don't have appropriate simulator installed, go to Xcode > Preferences > Components, there download and install whatever necessary.

Comment: only possible to test in real device not on simulator